# How can I properly format my Mongoose Schema to write JSON to my express API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**The Problem**:

I am developing an express.js API connected to a MongoDB Atlas Cloud instance. I would like to define a Mongoose schema that allows me to query the database.

I am currently just trying to make a GET request and write the response as JSON to one of my endpoints. When I run the server, I see an empty array at that endpoint and nothing else:

[image]

**My data is structured in my database  as follows**:

```
`
1._id: ObjectId("<AUTO_GENERATED_ID>")        ObjectId
2. lon: -87.37586979999998                    Double
3. lat: 27.1507649                            Double
4. otherproperty1: "<SOME_STRING>"            String
5. otherproperty2: "<SOME_STRING>"            String`
```

**My Schema and all relevant code:**

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = "mongodb+srv://<UN>-<PW>@cluster0-ptdbw.mongodb.net/<DB_NAME>"
let mongoDB = url
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
let db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error: '))`

`var Schema = mongoose.Schema
let ExampleSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  lon: {
    type: Schema.Types.Number
  },
  lat: {
    type: Schema.Types.Number
  },
  otherproperty1: {
    type: Schema.Types.String
  },
  otherproperty2: Schema.Types.String
})`

`var Instance = mongoose.model('Instance', ExampleSchema)`

`app.get('/schema', function (req, res, err) {
  Instance.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs)
  })
})`
```

Any tips on how I can get more than just an empty array?

Comment: The `[]` result indicates that there aren't any `Instance` objects in the db, are there?

Comment: It looks like your db is empty

Comment: @JDunken The collection size is over 18MB. I'm pretty new to Mongoose and MongoDB in general, so my guess is that I'm not connecting to my database appropriately. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Léo Martin The collection size is over 18MB. I'm pretty new to Mongoose and MongoDB in general, so my guess is that I'm not connecting to my database appropriately. Any suggestions?

Comment: `mongoose.connect` returns a Promise, maybe you could wait for it and catch any connection error